# Do I miss something in my proof?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, self-learning, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations

The post contains a problem and my solution to it. I am confusing with choosing $c$ since it depends on $p$ and I chose $p$ such that $|c| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$. Could you please check my solution and correct my mistakes if there is any? Thank you so much.

For a bounded interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ consider a Lipschitz continuous function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. Show that for arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ there is a polynomial $g(x)$ satisfying $g(x) = f(a)$, $g(b) =f(b)$ and

$$\| g'\|_{L^\infty(a,b)} \le \| f'\|_{L^\infty}(a,b) + \epsilon, \quad \|f-g\|_{L^\infty(a,b)} + \| f' -g'\|_{L^1 (a,b)} < \epsilon$$

**My solution**
It is clear that $f'$ is measurable function. By Lusin's theorem; given $\epsilon >0$ then there is a function $h:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

1- $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

2- The measure of $\{x:  h(x) \not= f'(x) \} $ is less than $ \epsilon$

3- $\| h\|_{L^\infty(a,b)} \leq \|f'\|_{L^\infty(a,b)}.$

By Weierstrass’ theorem there is a polynomial $p$ such that

$$\| h -p\|_{L^\infty(a,b)} < \frac{ \epsilon} {2}, \quad \,\,\text{ and }\,\, |c| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}.$$

where
$$c= \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}-\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b p(t)dt .$$

Now we define the function

$$g(x) := c (x-a) +f(a)+ \int_a^x p(t) dt, \quad c \in \mathbb{R}.$$

We have $g(a)= f(a)$, and $g(b) =f(b)$ and;
\begin{align*}
\| g'\|_{L^\infty(a,b)} &= \| c +  p \|_{L^\infty(a,b)}\\
& =\| c + p -h + h\|_{L^\infty(a,b)}\\
& \leq \|c\|_{L^\infty(a,b)} + \| p-h\|_{L^\infty(a,b)} +\|h\|_{L^\infty(a,b)}\\
& \leq \frac \epsilon 2 + \frac \epsilon 2 + \|h\|_{L^\infty(a,b)}\\
&\leq \|f'\|_{L^\infty(a,b)} + \epsilon
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \lVert f-g \rVert_{L^\infty(a,b)} & = \lVert f - c(x-a) - f(a) - \int_a^x p(t) dt \rVert_{L^\infty(a,b)} \\
    &= \lVert f(a) + \int_a^x f'(t) dt - c(x-a) +f(a) + \int_a^x p(t) dt \rVert_{L^\infty(a,b)}\\
    & \leq (b-a) \lVert f' - p \rVert_{L^\infty(a,b)}\\
    & \le (b-a) \left(\lVert f' -h\rVert_{L^\infty(a,b)} + \lVert h -p \lVert_{L^\infty(a,b)} \right)\\
    &\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \lVert f' -g' \rVert_{L^1(a,b)} &= \lVert f' -c - p \rVert_{L^1(a,b)}\\
    & \le \lVert f' -p \rVert_{L^1(a,b)}\\
    &\leq \lVert f'-h \rVert_{L^1(a,b)} + \lVert h -p \rVert_{L^1(a,b)}\\
    &\leq (b-a) \left( \lVert f'-h \rVert_{L^\infty(a,b)} +   \lVert h -p \rVert_{L^\infty(a,b)} \right)\\
    & \leq \epsilon
\end{align*}

Therefore, we get

$$ \lVert f-g \rVert_{L^\infty(a,b)} +  \lVert f' -g' \rVert_{L^1(a,b)} \leq \epsilon.$$

Comment: Your proof has many mistakes. The inequality on the end is wrong, the norm you used is not correct. What we know from p is just that is a good approximate, however, p is of mean zero is necessary and sufficient condition for g to be good approximate and satisfy the boundary condition, this is the role of c in fact. use c to make it happen; hint: p-c of mean zero.